# SAS New Variable Array from Single Variable

Tags: arrays, loops, sas

Should be an easy question that I cannot answer. I was given some survey data that had several questions that allowed "select as many that apply." For these questions, the response options are stored as a single variable separated by commas.

For example, say that question 1 (Q1) had 9 different response options. For that question, Person 1 might have three responses stored as: 1,3,10 whereas person 2 might have four responses stored as: 2,3,8,9.

From this single variable (Q1), I want to create 9 separate variables, one for each response option (Q1_1 to Q1_9). I believe I can do this in one DATA step with an ARRAY and a DO loop, but neither the INDEX or IN functions are working. Below is the code I've been using.

```
DATA Final; SET Final; 
     ARRAY Q1b{9} Q1_1 - Q1_9; *new variables I want to create;
     DO i = 1 TO 9;
         IF NOT MISSING(Q1) THEN Q1b{i} = 0; *works;
         IF INDEX(Q1,"i") THEN Q1b{i} = 1; *Doesn't work;
         IF Q1 IN: ("i") THEN Q1b{i} = 1; *Doesn't work either;
     END;
RUN;
```

Using responses from the example people above, the value of Q1_1 for person 1 would be 1, whereas for person 2 it would be 0. Likewise, the value of Q1_2 for person 1 would be 0, whereas for person 2 it would be 1. I'm guessing it has something with how SAS stores the looping i (I'm thinking of it similar to a macro variable without the &). Thought are appreciated.

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: With I in quotes it's looking for the character i, not the iterator i. Remove the quotes from the i.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INDEX() needs character strings.

```
IF INDEX(Q1,cats(i)) THEN Q1b{i} = 1;
```

Note that will not scale if there are more than 9 possible responses since the digit '1' will appear in both '1' and '10'.    So you might want to use INDEXW() instead.  Make sure to include space in addition to comma as a delimiter to prevent trailing spaces or spaces around the commas from becoming part of the words in the string.

```
IF INDEXW(Q1,cats(i),' ,') THEN Q1b{i} = 1;
```

Boolean expressions evaluate to 0 or 1.  So your program could just be:

```
data WANT;
  set HAVE;
  array q1_ [9] ;
  do i = 1 to dim(q1_);
    q1_[i] = 0<indexw(q1,cats(i),' ,');
  end;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks, Tom. This gets me very close, but fails to correctly identify the last response option given there is no trailing comma. For example, person 1 had responses: 1,3,10. For that person, Q1_1 and Q1_3 would have values of 1, but Q1_10 would have a value of 0.

Comment: Lack of a trailing comma is NOT an issue.  If there is some other character before or after the last word, like a carriage return, '0D'x, linefeed, '0A'x, or a non-breaking space, 'A0'x then the '10' would not seen as the last word in the string.  Either remove such characters are add them to the list of delimiters in the INDEXW() function call.  If you have spaces around the commas include space in the delimiters.

Comment: Perhaps it is the trailing spaces in the fixed length Q1?  Try adding space as a delimiter or trimming Q1 in the function call.

Comment: Trailing spaces due to fixed length was the issue. Thank you! Here is the line of code that worked: 

IF INDEXW(TRIM(Q1),CATS(i),',') THEN Q1b{i} = 1;

Answer (score 0):

- Generally shouldn't use the same input and output data set name. Makes it hard to debug and you sometimes get unexpected output.
- Check if the variable is empty before the loop to save you from loop unneccesarily
- Remove the quotes from the i to use the number i. In quotes it's looking for the letter i, not the iterator variable i.

Something like this maybe:

```
DATA Final_expanded; /*1*/
SET Final; 
     ARRAY Q1b{9} Q1_1 - Q1_9; *new variables I want to create;
     if not missing(q1) then DO i = 1 TO 9; /*2*/
         IF INDEX(Q1, i) THEN Q1b{i} = 1; /*3*/
     END;
RUN;
```

EDIT: couldn't get that to work for some reason but this method does work.

```
DATA Final_expanded; /*1*/
SET have; 
     ARRAY Q1b{9} Q1_1 - Q1_9; *new variables I want to create;
     nwords = countw(q1);
     if not missing(q1) then DO i = 1 TO nwords; /*2*/
         index = scan(q1, i);
         q1b(index) = 1;
     END;
RUN;
```

Comment: INDEX() function needs two CHARACTER arguments.  If it ran at all it would look for 1 with 11 leading spaces instead of '1'.